# How to pass simple `extends` in ESLint CLI

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Considering the very simple `eslintrc.yml` file below (default config for a pure Node project using TypeScript` and Prettier):

```yaml
env:
  node: true
  es2022: true

extends:
  - eslint:recommended
  - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended

parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'

parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: module

plugins:
  - '@typescript-eslint'
```

For various reasons, I tried to get rid of all my `.config.****.yml` for only CLI commands.

I'm able to translate almost all my ESLint configuration except the `extends` part (and I find nothing in the docs).

```bash
npx eslint
    --no-eslintrc
    --env node,es2022
    --parser @typescript-eslint/parser
    --parser-options ecmaVersion:latest
    --parser-options sourceType:module
    --plugin @typescript-eslint
    --fix
    .
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No, you can see it's not listed in https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed I think though even if find it weird. No possibility all with the new (?) [www.npmjs.com/package/@eslint/js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eslint/js)  inside `--plugin`?